# Simple Field extensions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Suppose $[L:K]=p$ $p$=prime .Then there exists $u$ such that $L=K(u)$

Proof.If  $[L:K]=p$ $p$=prime then for $M$ an  arbitrary field extension must hold that  $$[L:K]=[L:M][M:K]$$ if $[L:K]=prime$ then either $[L:M]=1$ or $[M:K]$=1 if the first one is  true then $L=M$ for arbitrary field extension so it is true for $L=K(u)$ .

Now if the second one is true $M=K$ and i cant find argument that can prove that exists $u$ such that $L=K(u)$ only that for any extension i get K=M therefore K(u)=K.

THat is my question on how to solve the second part

Comment: Take any $u\in L$. What options are there for $K(u)$?

Comment: Either $K(u)=L$ or $K(u)=K$ if $K(u)=K$ what do i say?

Comment: Well, you pick a different $u$ ;) Under what conditions is $K(u) = K$?

Comment: Ohhhhh If for all $u$ $K=K(u)$ then $L=K=K(u)$ if not then there exist $u$ such that $K(u) \neq K$ then it must be again $L=K(u)$ since i proved that for any arbitrary extension holds the above.

Comment: Yep. Of course $L = K$ cannot be since $1$ isn't prime.

Answer (score -1):

Take a element u in L which is not in K consider the field K(u) which contains K properly and using multiplicative properties of degree we can show that degree of K(u) over K is 1 or p since is not degree 1 hence it must be p and hence it is equal to L itself because it contained in L also has same degree.